# Tracking package dependencies in pre-release builds

Tags: ros, catkin, pre-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**TL;DR:** How do I define dependencies between not-yet-released catkin packages in `distribution.yaml` such that their dependencies are resolved during the automatic build that is triggered by new commits.

I added two catkin packages (from separate git repos) to the `distribution.yaml` mainly for generating documentation and for automatic tests on the build farm. Let's call these packages `L` (a driver library) and `N` (a ROS node with `L` as dependency). Both of these packages have not been released yet.

As I understand from these topics:

http://answers.ros.org/question/238430/first-release-of-packages-with-cross-dependencies/
http://answers.ros.org/question/190065/jenkins_scripts-how-to-resolve-source-dependencies-in-our-own-ros-jenkins/

the build farm cannot track the dependency on `L` when building `N` because `L` has not been released yet. E.g. a pre-release build will fail with the script generated at `http://prerelease.ros.org` if only package `N` is selected. I can workaround this in local pre-release builds by selecting both packages (`L`and `N`) in the pre-release script generation.

I don't want to release `L` yet because it is still in development and I would need to re-release it every time when I change its interface or behaviour. However, I want to use the continuous integration feature on the build farm, e.g. get notification on failed builds. Currently, the build fails each time I commit to `N` because its dependency on `L` cannot be resolved automatically.

The build of `N` definitely succeeds if `L` is checked out manually. Thus, how do I define the dependency between `N` and `L` such that `L` gets checked out when `N` is built?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251189/tracking-package-dependencies-in-pre-release-builds/) by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2017-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For documentation you can reference other repository names using the `depends` entry (see [REP 141](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0141.html#distribution-file)). An example making use of this is [multiwii](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/f891f7053796da770efe0b4a92a53a0b8a5d9a57/kinetic/distribution.yaml#L2881).

For the devel jobs no such information exists. A devel job operates only on a single repository and installs all its dependencies from Debian packages. Since those are not available for `L` it doesn't work for your repository `N`. Therefore you might want to disable the devel job for repo `N` for now which you can do by adding `test_commits: false` to the `source` entry (see [an example](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/f891f7053796da770efe0b4a92a53a0b8a5d9a57/kinetic/distribution.yaml#L3083)).

A `depends` entry could be added to `source` blocks too. Then the `devel` job would need to be a hybrid of the devel and prerelease process. We haven't implemented since its use is very limited. E.g. if you want to make correlated changes to `L` and `N` (e.g. change API and use the modified API) a pull request job would still fail. Simply because it uses the branch from one repo (e.g. `N`) but not the one from `L`. So you need a prerelease job to cover this case. If you on the other hand just commit the changes to `L` without trying if `N` actually works with it the failing CI job of `N` is pretty late (and would e.g. not even be triggered if you don't commit to `N` after committing the change to `L`).

For adding a `depends` entry for the `source` block it would require an updated version of REP 143 (the successor of REP 141) as well as support from the buildfarm. If you see a need for this it would be great if you could work on PRs for this. I am happy to help in that process.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1